# How PostgreSQL orders the data while using a DISTINCT * option

Tags: postgresql

When i use SELECT * FROM table, PostgreSQL is returning the data ordered by id. But when i use SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table, PostgreSQL is returning the same dataset as there are no duplicates but the order has been changed which is beyond my understanding.
How does PostgreSQL sort the data while using DISTINCT * and without specifying any ORDER BY clause.

Comment: "*is returning the data ordered by id.*" - no it's not. The **only** way to get a sorted result is to use `order by`. Any order you see without an order by is just coincidence. `distinct *`  doesn't really make sense as the `*` include the primary key columns and thus there will never be duplicates to begin with.

Comment: True. I agree with you distinct * doesn't make sense. I was trying to understand how it affects sorting as i just happened to observe the changes in sorting pattern while just playing around with data that makes me curious. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `DISTINCT` into a query, PostgreSQL sorts the result set by *all* result columns in order to eliminate duplicates. The sort order is “implementation defined” unless you add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

Two remarks:

- without the `DISTINCT`, the table is returned in `id` order because you inserted it that way and performed no updates or deletes, and because there are no concurrent sequential scans on the table. You can never rely on an order in the result set unless you use `ORDER BY`.
- `DISTINCT` can be very expensive on large result sets. Use it only if you are certain you need it.